# how can i add the namespace name before the attribute in xml using simplexml

Tags: simplexml

how can i add namespace name before a attribute of newly created tag,like

```
<Data ss:Type="String">this the value of data</Data>
```

but can create only

```
<Data Type="String">this the value of data</Data>
```

so i can not add "ss:" before atttbute.

Thanks in Advance

Have Dream Day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [SimpleXml PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addAttribute.php) someone gave a good example in the comments section.

Here is how I got it to work.

Say you have the following XML in a file xml.php:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data>Dolly Parton</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data>Islands in the Stream</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data>what</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data>1-29-2010</Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
XML;
```

You can read in this file and add the attributes you want by using XPath.

```
 <?php 
        include("xml.php"); 

        $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

        $data = $sxe->xpath('//Data');

    foreach ($data as $value)
    {
        $value->addAttribute('ss:Type', 'String', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'); 
        }

        echo $sxe->asXML();

    ?>
```

This is the output I get:

```
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data xmlns:ss="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ss:Type="String">Dolly Parton</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data xmlns:ss="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ss:Type="String">Islands in the Stream</Data>
  </Cell>

  <Cell>
    <Data xmlns:ss="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ss:Type="String">what</Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data xmlns:ss="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ss:Type="String">1-29-2010</Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
```

Comment: hi Thanks you very much but still it is not working ,i can give code i want somthing like this
<Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Dolly Parton</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Islands in the Stream</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">254.233.11.33</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1-29-2010</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
and i try with
$data->addAttribute("ss:Type","String",'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet');

but still not working plz help out

have dream day

Comment: Ok, I added more code to my answer. Let me know if I am on the right path. Are you working in PHP or not?

Comment: yes i am working in php,thanks for help but i get by simpleDOM class in google code,then i copy the one element attribute to another,now i have amother query how to edit attributes values that have the namesapce,when i try to edit it create the new attribute 
without the namespace
$table[0]->setAttributes(array('ExpandedRowCount'=>5))
that output somthing like

<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="4" ss:ExpandedRowCount="4" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="54" ExpandedRowCount="5">

Thanks for everthing

have dream day

Comment: I think you are going to need to update the original question with more code. I couldn't find any documentation on setAttributes() to determine how to add in the namespace. Post more code in the original questions and I'll try to take a look.